# C# Razor and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to check a boolean value coming from my .NET `viewmodel` in my JavaScript. If the user isn't signed in meaning my boolean of `IsAnonymous` would be true, I need to fire off two JavaScript functions. If it's false, I don't want to call the functions. I need to do this because one of the functions calls an `ApplicationUser` object which doesn't exist if the person using the website isn't signed in. And therefore, it throws a Null Reference Exception.

I've tried this code in my `script` tag at the bottom of my razor page, but the `addBookmark` function gets called even if `Model.IsAnonymous` returns true. Since `addBookmark` requires an `ApplicationUser` object, I'm throwing an error.

```
if (!@Model.IsAnonymous) {
    if ($('.bookmark-btn').hasClass('bookmark-story-btn')) {
        addBookmark();
    } else {
        removeBookmark();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `if(!@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.IsAnonymous))) {` to convert to a javascript `boolean`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke it's not working but now that I put a breakpoint on it, I'm seeing that I can't even step into the if statement and that it's always calling the addbookmark function

Comment: That is possibly a separate issue, but you still need to convert it to a javascript `bool` (and you can simply test that by using `var isAnonymous = @Model.IsAnonymous; console.log(isAnonymous);` and you will see an error

Comment: Inspect the rendered HTML/JavaScript and ensure that the JS generated is actually valid.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it at your `View`!

```
@if (!Model.IsAnonymous)
{
    <script>
        if ($('.bookmark-btn').hasClass('bookmark-story-btn')) {
            addBookmark();
        } else {
            removeBookmark();
        }
    </script>
}
```